# Jquery's spinner ui.value not logging out value

Tags: jquery-ui

I would like this to log out the value of the input:

HTML:

```
<input id="spinner" />
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#spinner").spinner({
        change: function(event, ui) {
            console.log(ui.value)
        }
    }); 
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u9T5s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this:
http://jsfiddle.net/u9T5s/1/

```
$(function() {
    $("#spinner").spinner({
        change: function(event, ui) {
            console.log(this.value)
        }
    }); 
});
```

Use this.value instead of ui.value. This will take the current object to which the change function is attached.

Answer to comment: you implement different function one is change and one is spin.

Also change will execute one on blur after a real change happened an spin executes once up/down click is fired.

```
spin: function( event, ui ) {
        if ( ui.value > 10 ) {
          $( this ).spinner( "value", -10 );
          return false;
        } else if ( ui.value < -10 ) {
          $( this ).spinner( "value", 10 );
          return false;
        }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why the previous way is not working? It's provided in jqueryui's documentation http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#overflow

Answer (score 2):

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u9T5s/2/)**

I am not sure what the appropriate hook is as far as the jquery ui API goes, but here is a simple way to do this as well:

```
$(function() {
 $("#spinner").spinner(); 
 $('.ui-spinner-up').click(function(){
   console.log("Increased to "+$('#spinner').val()); 
 });
 $('.ui-spinner-down').click(function(){
   console.log("Decreased to "+$('#spinner').val()); 
 });    
});
```